# Does the RL agent take no action during mini-batch?

Tags: gradient-descent, reinforcement-learning, batch-normalization

I'd really appreciate your help.

Let's say I am using a mini-batch size of 4 playing an Atari game in the RL context. I understand that weights are updated only every 4 frames. But what does the RL agent do during the 3 extra frames? Does it do nothing and just wait? Does it take random actions? Does it take actions every frame based on the policy it currently has?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing several things together. Three, to be concise.

The first is frameskip coefficient. If it is 4, that means, than the environment repeats given action for 4 frames and returns you the fifth as well as the cumulated reward over these frames. At least, ALE and gym wrapper around it work like that.

The second thing is the weight update frequency -- how often you update your network. If it's 4, that means that you just update the network each 4th step. And you just use the network to get an action 3 times without training.

Finally, mini-batch size is simply the amount of examples, you want your network to train on.  Nothing fancy, just usual mini-batch parameter as in supervised learning.

Comment: thank you this was very helpful. I am also finding this blog very helpful: https://danieltakeshi.github.io/2016/11/25/frame-skipping-and-preprocessing-for-deep-q-networks-on-atari-2600-games/

Comment: Yes, this guy has also an awesome [repo](https://github.com/DanielTakeshi/Paper_Notes) with paper notes.